# how to get Json object in a nested Json data

Tags: python, json

from the below Json data I need to fetch values corresponding to AAAA and BBBB and assign it to variables i.e. List_AAAA = [9090, 9091] and List_BBBB = ['MONACO' , 'NICE']

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "xxxx",
    "description": "XXXXY",
    "descriptionFormat": "XZXZ",
    "children": [],
    "customFields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1111,
            "name": "dert",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": 45,
                    "name": "est",
                    "type": "erence"
                }
            ],
            "type": "alue"
        },
        
        {
            "fieldId": 1114,
            "name": "name_pe",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": 423255,
                    "name": "CN",
                    "type": "eference",
                    "referenceData": {
                        "ropagation": "ATE"
                    },
                    "euse": false
                }
            ],
            "type": "alue"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 1111111,
            "name": "Cases",
            "values": [
                [
                    {
                        "fieldId": 111121,
                        "name": "Case",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "AAAA": 9090,
                                "BBBB": "MONACO",
                                "ype": "eference",
                                "referenceData": {
                                    "ropagation": "ATE"
                                },
                                "euse": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "ames": [],
                        "type": "alue"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "fieldId": 111122,
                        "name": "Case",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "AAAA": 9091,
                                "BBBB": "NICE",
                                "ype": "eference",
                                "ata": {
                                    "ropagation": "ATE"
                                },
                                "euse": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "ames": [],
                        "ype": "alue"
                    }
                ],
```

It would also be great if someone who answers explains how it actually works. As I am not getting the logic behind how to parse through it

Comment: [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)

Comment: If you don't know where the "AAAA" and "BBBB" keys are relative to anything else in the dictionary, you'll need a recursive search

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively iterate over each element in the JSON object and extract the values depending on their type.

Example:

```py
import json


def extract_values(data, key):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if key in data:
            yield data[key]
        for value in data.values():
            yield from extract_values(value, key)
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            yield from extract_values(item, key)


List_AAAA = list(extract_values(data, "AAAA"))
```